# Change line type of vertex border

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a way to change the line type of the border of vertex in an igraph plot with R? For example, I'd like to make vertex with a dashed edge instead of a solid line.

*Update*: Here is example code that produces a node with a black border. I'm wondering if there's a way to make that black border a dashed black border (like 'lty = 2' in a standard R line plot):

```
library('igraph')
NodeList = data.frame('AA', x = 1 ,y = 1)
EdgeList = data.frame(from = 'AA', to = 'AA')
xgraph = graph_from_data_frame(vertices = NodeList, 
                               d = EdgeList, directed = TRUE)
plot(xgraph, vertex.shape = 'circle',
     vertex.size = 100, rescale = FALSE)
```

Comment: If you are having difficulty with a task your _should_ post the code you used to create your data objects and the code you used to make an attempt. Read [mcve]

Comment: @42- I generally agree, although in this case I felt the example code was trivial. Does the addition above make the question more approachable?

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-03/msg00030.html, but you need to add `lty="dashed"` to the `symbols(...)` function.

Comment: I got the code working from the citation from @user20650. Do you still need it, or was that reference enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh heck, I'll post it anyway. It's code after all. The credit should go to Gabor Csardi and @user20650. I think that citation is in a sufficiently stable location that we can expect it to be accessible in future years. :

```
png(width=200,height=200)
mycircle <- function(coords, v=NULL, params) {
  vertex.color <- params("vertex", "color")
  if (length(vertex.color) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.color <- vertex.color[v]
  }
  vertex.frame.lty  <- params("vertex", "lty")
    if (length(vertex.frame.lty) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
      vertex.frame.lty <- vertex.frame.lty[v]
  }
  vertex.size  <- 1/200 * params("vertex", "size")
  if (length(vertex.size) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.size <- vertex.size[v]
  }
  vertex.frame.color <- params("vertex", "frame.color")
  if (length(vertex.frame.color) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.frame.color <- vertex.frame.color[v]
  }
  vertex.frame.width <- params("vertex", "frame.width")
  if (length(vertex.frame.width) != 1 && !is.null(v)) {
    vertex.frame.width <- vertex.frame.width[v]
  }
  mapply(coords[,1], coords[,2], vertex.color, vertex.frame.color,
         vertex.size, vertex.frame.width, vertex.frame.lty,
         FUN=function(x, y, bg, fg, size, lwd, lty) {
           symbols(x=x, y=y, bg=bg, fg=fg, lwd=lwd, lty=lty,
                   circles=size, add=TRUE, inches=FALSE)
         })
}
dev.off()

add.vertex.shape("fcircle", clip=igraph.shape.noclip,
         plot=mycircle, parameters=list(vertex.frame.color=1, vertex.frame.lty=1,
                                  vertex.frame.width=1))

plot(xgraph, vertex.shape="fcircle", vertex.frame.color="red", vertex.size=100 ,vertex.lty=2,
     vertex.frame.width=2)
```

There was a warning that this might not be guaranteed to work if the igraph API changes:

[image]

Comment: Freaking awesome. I appreciate your interpretation because I was having a hard time working out the details with limited time.

Comment: I made several (10 actually) errors in implementation on my way to a final (?) version. Maybe I'm a bit better at reading sometimes opaque error messages than you?

Comment: thanks for this; one additional error I found which I do not understand, but was able to fix: when dealing with a dense (in the plotting sense) set of nodes, apparently there some sort of drawing collision. This can be resolved by setting the clip function to shapes("circle")$clip instead of the noclip one.